# 403 forbidden if name/url contains special character

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

We have many intranet document what linked on our intranet site. We use "apache builed in" directory listing to handle documents on browser. We try to use a template (h5ai) for mod_autoindex. Unfortunately if file or folder name contains special characters (like é,á,ű,ő,ú,ü,ö,ó) than get Access Forbidden - Error 403. If change the folder name, then it's okay.

I do it locally with Xampp server.

How to change the Apache config to not get error?

I downloaded the WAMP server. Install and make a new directory:

```
Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
```

And this is how its look like in browser: `%C1rv%EDzt%FBr%F5%20T%FCk%F6rf%FAr%F3g%E9p/`

And after I click on link get Access Forbidden error.